# Java configuration for security constraints in a Spring REST application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, configuration

I am building an application with Spring REST (without *web.xml*). REST calls are working fine but I need to add few security constraints which are easy to add through *web.xml* but as I am using Spring 4 without *web.xml* so I need help in adding the *web.xml* part through Java configuration.

My *web.xml*:

```xml
<security-role>
     <role-name>all</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>all</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I need help in configuring this *web.xml* through Java configuration. Probably this can be added through Spring Security but not sure how to that.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can implement security with your custom constraints using@Configuration  and overrride the configure method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

```
 @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        DataSource datasource;
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**")
                    .permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("user")
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    // Logout requires form submit. Bypassing the same.
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html").and()
                    .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                    .csrf().disable();

        }
}
```